# Why Ajax does not hit webmethod function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am using Jquery Ajax in Asp.net web form. But Ajax call does not hit my web method function. I tried many times with the solution of stack overflow. but it still not works.I also add breakpoint in webmethod function.but ajax not hitting it.It shows just error alert.I already tried more then five hours but it is not working.here is my code:

jquery Ajax code:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById("entryDate").value = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');
        var eTime = moment().format('HH:00');
        document.getElementById("entryTime").value = eTime;

        $("#saveButtonLabEntry").click(function () {
            alert("hi");

            var today = moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD');

            var eTime = moment().format('HH:00');

            var unitName = $('#unitName').val();

            var labEntryArray = [];
            var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable1");
            var rCount = tbl.rows.length;


            alert(rCount);
            try {
                for (var j = 1; j <= rCount - 1; j++) {
                    var sampleName = tbl.rows[j].cells[1].innerText;
                    var density15C = tbl.rows[j].cells[2].children[0].value;
                    var rvpPsi = tbl.rows[j].cells[3].children[0].value;
                    var colourAstm = tbl.rows[j].cells[4].children[0].value;
                    var fp0C = tbl.rows[j].cells[5].children[0].value;
                    var viscosity50C = tbl.rows[j].cells[6].children[0].value;
                    var viscosity100C = tbl.rows[j].cells[7].children[0].value;
                    var pp0C = tbl.rows[j].cells[8].children[0].value;
                    var ibp = tbl.rows[j].cells[9].children[0].value;
                    var astm5 = tbl.rows[j].cells[10].children[0].value;
                    var astm10 = tbl.rows[j].cells[11].children[0].value;
                    var astm50 = tbl.rows[j].cells[12].children[0].value;
                    var astm90 = tbl.rows[j].cells[13].children[0].value;
                    var astm95 = tbl.rows[j].cells[14].children[0].value;
                    var fbp = tbl.rows[j].cells[15].children[0].value;
                    var beforeOxid = tbl.rows[j].cells[16].children[0].value;
                    var afterOxid = tbl.rows[j].cells[17].children[0].value;
                    var report = tbl.rows[j].cells[18].children[0].value;
                    var fr5 = tbl.rows[j].cells[19].children[0].value;

                    //alert(fr5);
                    var obj = { unitname: unitName, SampleName: sampleName, Entrydate: today, EntryTime: eTime, Density15C: density15C, RVP_PSI: rvpPsi, colourASTM: colourAstm, FP: fp0C, Viscosity50: viscosity50C, Viscosity100: viscosity100C, pp: pp0C, ASTM_IBP: ibp, ASTM5: astm5, ASTM10: astm10, ASTM50: astm50, ASTM90: astm90, ASTM95: astm95, FBP: fbp, BSWB4Oxid: beforeOxid, BSWAfterOxid: afterOxid, Report: report, FR5xylene: fr5 };

                    labEntryArray.push(obj);
                }

            } catch (e) {
                alert("hello");
            }
            var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("LabEntryUI.aspx")%>';



            $.ajax(
            {
                //url: "LabEntryGateway.aspx/SaveLabData",
                url: pageUrl + '/SaveLabData',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(labEntryArray),
                success: function (da) {
                    //$("#msg").html(da.Message);
                    alert('success');
                },
                error: function (da) {
                    alert('hello Error');
                }

            });


        });
    });
</script>
```

LabEntryUI.aspx.cs Code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ERL.Gateway;
using ERL.Models;

namespace ERL
{
    public partial class LabEntryUI : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
       public static void SaveLabData(List<LabEntry> labEntryArray)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ERLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (
                    SqlCommand Command =
                        new SqlCommand("Insert into LabReport Values(@unitName,@sampleName,@entryDate,@entryTime," +
                                       "@userId,@density15C,@rvpPsi,@colourAstm,@fp,@viscosity50," +
                                       "@viscosity100,@pp,@astmIvp,@astm5,@astm10,@astm50,@astm90,@astm95,@fbp,@bswb4Oxid," +
                                       "@bswAfterOxid,@report,@fr5Xylene)"))
                {
                    Command.Parameters.Clear();
                    Command.Parameters.Add("unitName", SqlDbType.NChar);
                    Command.Parameters.Add("sampleName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    Command.Parameters.Add("entryDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                    Command.Parameters.Add("entryTime", SqlDbType.NChar);
                    Command.Parameters.Add("userId", SqlDbType.NChar);

                    Command.Parameters.Add("density15C", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    Command.Parameters.Add("rvpPsi", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    Command.Parameters.Add("colourAstm", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    Command.Parameters.Add("fp", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    Command.Parameters.Add("viscosity50", SqlDbType.Decimal);

                    Command.Parameters.Add("viscosity100", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    Command.Parameters.Add("pp", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    Command.Parameters.Add("astmIvp", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    Command.Parameters.Add("astm5", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    Command.Parameters.Add("astm10", SqlDbType.Decimal);

                    Command.Parameters.Add("astm50", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    Command.Parameters.Add("astm90", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    Command.Parameters.Add("astm95", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    Command.Parameters.Add("fbp", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    Command.Parameters.Add("bswb4Oxid", SqlDbType.Decimal);

                    Command.Parameters.Add("bswAfterOxid", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    Command.Parameters.Add("report", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    Command.Parameters.Add("fr5Xylene", SqlDbType.Decimal);


                    foreach (var labEntry in labEntryArray)
                    {
                        Command.Parameters["unitName"].Value = labEntry.unitname;
                        Command.Parameters["sampleName"].Value = labEntry.SampleName;
                        Command.Parameters["entryDate"].Value = labEntry.Entrydate;
                        Command.Parameters["entryTime"].Value = labEntry.EntryTime;
                        Command.Parameters["userId"].Value = "";
                        Command.Parameters["density15C"].Value = labEntry.Density15C;

                        Command.Parameters["rvpPsi"].Value = labEntry.RVP_PSI;
                        Command.Parameters["colourAstm"].Value = labEntry.colourASTM;
                        Command.Parameters["fp"].Value = labEntry.FP;
                        Command.Parameters["viscosity50"].Value = labEntry.Viscosity50;
                        Command.Parameters["viscosity100"].Value = labEntry.Viscosity100;
                        Command.Parameters["pp"].Value = labEntry.pp;
                        Command.Parameters["astmIvp"].Value = labEntry.ASTM_IBP;
                        Command.Parameters["astm5"].Value = labEntry.ASTM5;
                        Command.Parameters["astm10"].Value = labEntry.ASTM10;
                        Command.Parameters["astm50"].Value = labEntry.ASTM50;
                        Command.Parameters["astm90"].Value = labEntry.ASTM90;
                        Command.Parameters["astm95"].Value = labEntry.ASTM95;
                        Command.Parameters["fbp"].Value = labEntry.FBP;
                        Command.Parameters["bswb4Oxid"].Value = labEntry.BSWB4Oxid;
                        Command.Parameters["bswAfterOxid"].Value = labEntry.BSWAfterOxid;
                        Command.Parameters["report"].Value = labEntry.Report;
                        Command.Parameters["fr5Xylene"].Value = labEntry.FR5xylene;

                        Command.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();

                        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

LabEntry class Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ERL.Models
{
    public class LabEntry
    {
        public int sl { get; set; }
        public string unitname { get; set; }
        public string SampleName { get; set; }
        public DateTime Entrydate { get; set; }
        public string EntryTime { get; set; }
        public string userid { get; set; }
        public decimal Density15C { get; set; }
        public decimal RVP_PSI { get; set; }
        public string colourASTM { get; set; }
        public decimal FP { get; set; }
        public decimal Viscosity50 { get; set; }
        public decimal Viscosity100 { get; set; }
        public decimal pp { get; set; }
        public decimal ASTM_IBP { get; set; }
        public decimal ASTM5 { get; set; }
        public decimal ASTM10 { get; set; }
        public decimal ASTM50 { get; set; }
        public string ASTM90 { get; set; }
        public string ASTM95 { get; set; }
        public decimal FBP { get; set; }
        public decimal BSWB4Oxid { get; set; }
        public decimal BSWAfterOxid { get; set; }
        public string Report { get; set; }
        public decimal FR5xylene { get; set; }
        public int slWater { get; set; }
        public string SampleNameWater { get; set; }
        public decimal ph { get; set; }
        public decimal COND { get; set; }
        public decimal TDS { get; set; }
        public decimal TA { get; set; }
        public decimal TAC { get; set; }
        public decimal NACL { get; set; }
        public decimal H2S { get; set; }
        public decimal NH3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please also share code of your `LabEntry` class?

Comment: Updated. please check

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint inside your webservice method? I think the error is generated by the code for updating data in database and that's why error callback is called on client-side. Instead of alerting the error, try `console.log(da)`

Comment: i already put a breakpoint inside webmethod. but it is not hitting at all. just show error alert message

Comment: Update code inside your error callback like this: `error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
      console.log(xhr.statusText);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(error);
  }` and check what is the output in browser developer console

Comment: Console Shows:   Internal Server Error                                                                                           Error                                                                                                         Internal Server Error

Comment: Launch browser developer tools click on `Network` tab and then perform some action on the screen which will trigger the POST call. You will see a row under Network tab for the network call, click on that call to drill into the details and then click on the `Response` tab on the right pane to check the response or error details.

Comment: Here is the error:     Type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported for deserialization of an array.

Comment: You're sending a string to the method, but the method expects a `List<LabEntry>`. You won't be able to do that. Change the method to accept a string. Inside the method, deserialize the string to a `List<LabEntry>`. Test first with a simple string to see if the method is hit.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your jquery code for posting data like this. Here json represents an object with one property `labEntryArray` holding an array of LabEntry objects

```
data: JSON.stringify({labEntryArray:labEntryArray})
```

Instead of

```
data: JSON.stringify(labEntryArray)
```